# Microsoft.AspNetCore.App - Do Azure Pipelines work with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-pipelines, dependency-management

**My Question**

How do I reference framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' and have Azure Pipeline(s) build successfully?

**Context**

I'm getting started with Azure DevOps and have hit my first sticking point.

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 encountering this issue, only when building in Azure DevOps. Local builds are fine; the application runs fine. I figure there's something off about my pipeline setup, but I'm struggling to identify exactly what. Here's my error:

> SampleClass.cs(69,19): error CS1705: Assembly 'Sample' with identity 'Sample, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

The offending dependencies in **Sample**'s project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

...    

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.14.0" />
```

I believe this is the culprit because it lines up w/ [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1705):

- implicit reference to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.App resolves ...Http.Abstraction.dll at version **3.1.0**.
- including the package reference resolves the ...Http.Abstraction.dll at version **1.0.2**.

So the issue is at least explained; *the wrong file is on disk* - in Azure Pipelines. On my local machine, I see the framework Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref package installed with all the 3.1.0 assemblies. When I remove the app insights dependency, I get new type errors indicating the wrong version is being restored during build.

**What do I need to consider to troubleshoot why *the wrong file* is being restored in Azure Pipelines?**

I've verified

- that build agent [should have the runtime I need installed already](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md) (.NET Core 3.1.0 covered),
- the msbuild.exe command being used by Azure DevOps succeeds for me locally,
- removing the app insights dependency does not resolve the issue (only changes it to an "are you missing an assembly" error).

> msbuild.exe "path\to\Sample.sln" /nologo /nr:false /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="16.0"

**Why would this work fine for me locally, but fail in other environments?**

Comment: "Do Azure Pipelines work with ASP.NET Core?"...it would be pretty shortsighted of Microsoft if they didn't...anyway I've used one and yes it does. In fact it can work with almost any language / platform if you set it up. TBH though I just clicked a button in Visual Studio during the publish process and it set the whole pipeline up for me automatically, no configuration required (except for telling it the target azure web app to deploy to).

Comment: Why are using `msbuild.exe` instead of dotnet CLI or built-in Azure DevOps tasks?

Comment: I "just clicked a button in Visual Studio during the publish process and it set the whole pipeline up for me automatically, no configuration required", but the configuration doesn't play nice with my references (and I don't know why).

Comment: According the error "uses 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0", I have not see that version with nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/, would you please share how your Sample project use that package?

Comment: In this situation I found it much eaiser to switch to using .NET Core tasks (instead of the Nuget/VS tasks that were auto-generated). I was referencing 3.1.0.0 implicitly through the project file pointing to  Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" (or so I understand).